# ajax-datatables-rails aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables-1.10

I have implemented ajax-datatables-rails for one table where I get raw records with query using group

```
    class ListcontractorsDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base

  def view_columns
    # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
    # or in aliased_join_table.column_name format
    @view_columns ||= {
       id: { source: "Contractor.id", cond: :eq },
       name: { source: "Contractor.name" },
       city: { source: "Contractor.city" },
       ico: { source: "Contractor.ico" },
       country: { source: "Contractor.country" },
       count: {source: "Contract.count"}
    }
  end
def_delegators :@view, :link_to, :showcontractor_path, :content_tag
  def data
    records.map do |contractor|
      {
        # example:
         id: contractor.id,
         name: link_to(contractor.name, showcontractor_path(contractor.id)),
         city: contractor.city,
         ico: contractor.ico,
         country: contractor.country,
         count: contractor.count,
         extlink: link_to(content_tag(:i,nil,class: 'fa fa-external-link'), 'https://www.somepage.com/'+contractor.ico.to_s)
        }
    end
  end
  private
def get_raw_records
  Contractor.joins(:contracts).select("contractors.id,name,ico,city,country,count(resultinfo_id) as count")
              .group("contractors.id,contractors.name,contractors.ico,contractors.city,contractors.country")

end

end
```

everything works (ordering, pagination, all columns are correct) except search. When I put anything into search I got error

> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in
>   WHERE

I cannot find any working solution with group in query for branch 0.4.0. Could you please help me? thx

Comment: can you post the console SQL that fail?

Comment: here is how-to project for branch-0-4 https://github.com/ajahongir/ajax-datatables-rails-v-0-4-0-how-to . It will be great to put sql query here.

Comment: is there any solution for this? I am facing same error 2 years later